# Enable and disabled multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to enable/disable multiple inputs when a select change. It works but I want to do it better. How can I improve my code?

```
$("#street_type").on("change", function(event){
    if( $(this).val() == 1){
        $("#clase_via").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#nombre_via").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#numero_via").prop('disabled', true);
        ...
        $("#indicaciones").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    if( $(this).val() == 2){
        $("#clase_via").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#nombre_via").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#numero_via").prop('disabled', false);
        ...
        $("#indicaciones").prop('disabled', false);
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Create array with id's of needled input's:

```
var inputs = ["clase_via", ...], i, count;
for (i = 0, count = inputs.length; i < count; i += 1){
    $(inputs[i]).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Add "data" attribute for needled input's:

```
<input type='text' data-lockable="true"/>
$("input [data-lockable='true']).prop("disabled", true);
```

Place all input's into one block and call jQuery as:

```
$("#maindiv > input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is putting a class for all the items you want enabled/disabled:

```
$(".class_name").prop('disabled', true);` and `$(".class_name").prop('disabled', false);
```